# How to control Facebook share information for the front page?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to prove information to Facebook so I can control what the title and description information is that comes up when pasting the front page of my blog on facebook?

Right now, it seems to grab a random post... not the latest... for th information. I'd prefer to either set the information myself for the front page OR insure that it shows information from my 1st/featured post.

How can I get control over this?

(again, this isn't related to a "like" button, or anything... but posting the root URL straight to a Facebook status. Sharing the whole site, not a post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the Open Graph metadata?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

I think that should give Facebook the right hints.