# Choices for thumbnail image in a Facebook Link post

Tags: facebook, images

When I'm posting a link for a WordPress page or post on a Facebook Page wall (using the "Post a link" option), I want Facebook to offer up, as choices, (a) all images which are embedded in the linked page/post as well as (b) a set of default images (in case the page/post in question has no embedded images).

What I've done is add (to wp_head) several candidate images in separate link rel="img_src" tags.

The problem is that these link rel tags appear to override any images that are actually embedded in the page/post.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Plugin that manipulates the data sent via the Facebook Open Graph Protocol, e.g. [Facebook Opengraph](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-opengraph/). There are [several others, also](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook%20opengraph&sort=).

**Related Posts**

- [How to control Facebook share information for the front page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8407/how-to-control-facebook-share-information-for-the-front-page)
- [Facebook is only displaying preview thumbnails that are 100px from my posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12613/facebook-is-only-displaying-preview-thumbnails-that-are-100px-from-my-posts)
- [Facebook sharing link is not showing a thumbnail of the images within the post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/facebook-sharing-link-is-not-showing-a-thumbnail-of-the-images-within-the-post)
- [Lots more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook%20opengraph)

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the images in the head, do a query on the posts ID to find posts that are of the post type attachment with the parent ID equal to that of the current post. Then use these attachments to generate the image URLs in your header via [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) .

This way the 'candidate' images will always be images attached to the current post